Does a C pointer to volatile treat the addressed memory as volatile when it is subscripted?
Consider these two definitions:
volatile int a[10];
volatile int *p = a; 

EDIT: clarify question.
If we refer to a[3] that memory location will be treated as volatile storage, that is, the compiler will make no assumptions about it staying the same.
For an array, it is clear that the intention is that the entire contents of the array are treated as volatile.
Is it the case also in C that p[3] also refers to volatile storage, though p is declared as a pointer, and not as an array? In other words, in an expression using a "pointer to volatile", such as p[3] or *(p + 3) is the volatile "infectious", and does it apply to memory locations other than the exact one pointed to by the pointer to volatile?
I do know what it means for the compiler to treat memory as volatile.

Both refer to potential volatile memory.

@chux The term volatile memory means an entirely different thing not related to the question what-so-ever. It means physical memory which loses data when the supply voltage is removed.

@Lundin "It means physical memory which loses data when the supply voltage is removed." That's a far too narrow definition of "volatile". And it's for sure not how it's used in the C standard

I have rewritten the question to make clear that I was asking about using a volatile pointer in an expression and whether the volatile is then applicable to memory not directly pointed to by the pointer.

@4386427 Like it or not, that's the industry standard definition of the term. Volatile memory. This is an existing, widely used term used by software engineers and other professionals. Luckily, there exists no term in C programming called "volatile memory" nor "volatile storage" so we need to worry out pretty heads about those non-existing terms in the context of C programming.

@DanHalbert Regarding the edit, the last paragraph in my answer actually answers that. What's relevant from C23 and beyond is "volatile lvalue access": the type used during de-referencing. Whereas in C17 or older standards this was worded incorrectly since they only mentioned volatile objects. Meaning that some language-lawyer compiler person might in theory decide that *(volatile int*)123 does not count as a volatile object access and then optimize away that code.

@Lundin Re "means physical memory which loses data when the supply voltage is removed.":  That is a reasonable possibility based on the title. OP did syntax highlight volatile in the C question body & post volatile in the code sample. With volatile tag "Volatile is a qualifier used to define a data storage area (object, field, variable, parameter) that "can change on its own", I concluded OP asked about that in this programming site & not volatile memory.


Is it the case in C that p[3] also refers to volatile storage...

Yes, volatile int *p makes p a pointer to volatile int. So any access made using p (aka dereference of p) will be considered a volatile access to memory.
Note that p itself isn't volatile. It's only what p points to that are volatile.
Not that it's a proof but for fun, you can try removing "volatile" from p like:
volatile int a[10];
int *p = a;

Compiling this with e.g. gcc gives you a warning like:
warning: initialization discards 'volatile' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

which makes it pretty clear that something is wrong as p no longer points to volatile int.
BTW:
Constant pointer vs Pointer to constant could be an interesting read. It's about const instead of volatile but the principle is the same.

The first paragraph I believe answers my question, though not quite directly.

"So any access made using p (aka dereference of p) will be considered an access to volatile memory."  This is not really what the standard says. It says "Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine." Emphasis on volatile object. Which in turn is a language defect. In C23 it will say "Volatile accesses to objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine." There is a new formal term volatile access which didn't exist before.

So it would be better to call it a "volatile access to memory" rather than an "access to volatile memory". The fix in C23 correcting the defect in the wording of earlier versions of the standard merely makes the new standard conform to actual practice by existing compilers.

I'm not sure why everyone is on about "volatile storage" as if it would mean something special.
volatile is simply a keyword in C telling the compiler not to make any assumptions about a variable, never to optimize it and always to reload it from memory before using it. That's it. The most common usage is hardware-related programming: memory mapped hardware registers, DMA buffers etc.
To point at a variable declared as volatile, the pointer must also have the volatile qualifier as in your code. When a qualifier (volatile or const etc) is placed left of the * in the pointer declaration, it refers to the pointed-at data. Thus:
volatile int* x; // pointer to volatile data
int* volatile y; // volatile pointer to non-volatile data

"Casting away" the qualifier is generally undefined behavior. Also, the rules of assignment say that for x = y, x must have at least all qualifiers of y, but not necessarily the way around.
As for arrays, they "decay" into pointers to the first element when used in most expressions. And the pointer obtained from "decay" comes with all the qualifiers of the array item. So a in your case will become volatile int* when used in most expressions.
Whenever an object is access through a volatile qualified pointer, the same rules apply as when accessing the object directly.
(There's been a hiccup in the C standard here until now which will finally get fixed in upcoming C23. Until now the C standard has spoken of access to declared volatile objects counting as a side effect. In C23 this has been fixed to include all lvalue access of volatile-qualified types.)

"Casting away" the qualifier is allowed as long as it is not used to override the qualifiers on the object. For example:volatile void *p = malloc(42); free((void *)p); is perfectly fine because allocated objects are not volatile.

@IanAbbott There is nothing in the C standard supporting or forbidding such casts. Strict aliasing does not mention qualifiers at all. Pointer conversions mention casting from non-qualified to qualified but not the other way around.

Qualified object types have the same alignment requirement as non-qualified object types, so by C17 6.3.2.3p7 there is no problem converting a "qualified object" pointer type to a "less qualified object" pointer type. Any UB will come from dereferencing the pointer. (BTW, I'm the up voter, not the down voter.)

@IanAbbott 6.3.2.3p2 is the relevant part. It remains silent about the case going from  qualified type to non-qualified. That part is simply missing and that's a mistake in the standard.

Because "volatile storage" is in the question.

@Lundin, volatile* int x; did not compile for me.  Did you want volatile int *x;?

@chux That's a typo indeed, thanks.

Re “Strict aliasing does not mention qualifiers at all”: Yes, it does. An object may be aliased with more qualifiers and not with less. Among the types allowed for aliasing listed in C 2018 6.5 7 is “a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object.” So in int x; void foo(const int *p) { … }, *p may alias x, but, in const int x; void foo(int *p) { … }, *p may not alias x, not even for a read access.

Object types include the qualifiers (if any) so 6.3.2.3p7 should apply regardless of 6.3.2.3p2 if I'm reading it correctly.

@EricPostpischil But it isn't clear if effective type includes qualifiers or not.

@Lundin: C 2018 6.5 of an object with a declared type is the declared type. It does not say it is the unqualified version of the type. So if the declared type is qualified, the effective type is the same type. Similarly, for other cases, where the effective type comes from one lvalue or another, it says the effective type is the type of the lvalue, and again it does not say any qualifiers are removed. The effective type is simply the type of the lvalue, with whatever qualifiers it has.

Contrary to popular belief, declaring volatile int doesn't make anything volatile storage, it just tells the compiler to treat it as so.
volatile doesn't work for multithreading issues except on x86 because the memory model of other processors is weaker, and the compiler doesn't emit the necessary instructions. volatile only tells the compiler to not optimize out the variable access, not to emit memory barriers.
What will happen is any access into a or any access to through p wherever it points will not be optimized away. That's it, neither more nor less.
Actual volatile memory is declared like this: extern volatile int trisa; and the definition is provided by an object file that cannot be written in standard c. volatile is for memory-mapped IO. It has other purposes but that's the why it was created. When the specification in setjmp() refers to volatile it knows something the compiler doesn't; setjmp() trashes the call-preserved registers, so treating the locals like volatile memory works correctly.

The context of this is that the code in question is actually writing an array of control registers starting at a specific address on a microcontroller in a specific order, which is a typical use for volatile. I was just trying to reduce the question to a C language spec question.

@DanHalbert: I see. I hope my answer was useful anyway. But in your case I would now rather refer you to your vendor's compiler manual. On the last processor I worked with, pointers to control registers behaved oddly.

I have no idea why you brought up multi-threading, it has nothing to do with the question. As far as I know, there is no common term "volatile storage", not in the context of multithreading and not in any other context either.

@Lundin: Most people trying to use volatile in modern C are trying to use it to solve their thread race issues. I had no idea when writing it that he was trying to declare hardware registers.

@Joshua Concerning most  in "Most people trying to use volatile", I suspect that is a survey bias that is quite dependent on the programmers in which you move.
